# When a touch-up paint doesn't match, and you need to paint "corner to corner" is one wall usually sufficient?

Tags: drywall, painting

Say I have a drywall repair that I need to paint over, and the previous owner of the house didn't leave a can of paint in this room's particular color, so I go try to get a gallon of matched paint somewhere, and it ends up not being a perfect match. I've heard in this case you have to paint "corner to corner", which I assume just means painting the whole wall, and not necessarily the whole room.

If that's the case, does this usually work out okay? Or is it often noticeable enough to where you need to paint the entire room?

Comment: If doing corner to corner, could also use a different colour that accents the other walls.  A patch job for a small area is harder to match depending on the age, matching paint for paint.

Comment: Note that _if_ the paint isn't a perfect match, you'll need to _very_ carefully mask off the adjoining walls or be _very_ detailed when you brush into the corner. If you get any new paint on the adjoining wall, wipe it off _immediately_! If you don't, you'll have little spots of the new color on an old color wall and you'll end up having to paint that wall, too.

Comment: but then the colours will match.

Comment: you can also slightly adjust a single wall's color/sheen by changing the light that hits it.

Comment: Or you could use the tried-and-true method of "hang a picture over it".  (Only if it's at an appropriate height I guess.  If the patch is near the floor it'd be kind of weird...)

Comment: I went with the picture technique for a couple of years, but now I have to move, so I wanted to clean things up properly for the next owner.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Another approach is to figure out an accent design which will conveniently cover over the places where the original paint was damaged.  If all defects are near a corner, for example, one could decorate all of the corners with vertical accent stripes.  If all defects are at about the same elevation, depending upon what the elevation is, one could paint an accent stripe around the room.

Comment: It may be good enough, it may not. Nobody here can tell any better than you can, and it will depend on lots of other factors like lighting, paint color, finish texture, etc. I voted to close--not because it is a bad question--because, as written, all anyone can do here is offer opinions and speculation. Please consider revising your question to make it more friendly for factual answers if you can.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because colors look a little different on different walls because of different light angles, different reflections and shadows, a *well* matched paint should not have to go beyond the surface that extends directly from the patch.

To match paint well you need to choose the right brand and finish correctly (gloss, etc) and use the right tool (roller, brush).  Not merely to let the computer pick the right mix.  The paint store employee needs skill and care, and so do you.

I have had matches where I only paint the patch and even I can't see it the next day!

Comment: +1. Bring a sample of the existing paint (take a small square of the drywall if you're doing repairs anyway!) and the paint store should be able to get a really good match - last time I did this I couldn't see the patch once the paint dried. Just like when buying any other paint, I'd go to an actual paint store and not the home center.

Comment: Ive had luck with "drybrushing" with the paint roller a couple feet around the patch. Saturate the roller and then paint the patch, and then from there, you use the roller after almost all the paint has been rolled off, so it kind of feathers the paint out and almost mixes the old and new colours together.

Answer (score 4):

It depends how close the new colour is. You really won't know until you try it.
Modern scan/repro techniques ought to be closer than a 'by eye' match, but surface/brush texture/reflectivity can make the perceived colour of the end result seem further out than if all walls were facing the exact same light source. On the other hand you might just get lucky & the lighting changes work to mask any difference. This may even change depending on time of day, sunlight vs artificial light.

It will drive you mad every single time you walk in the room for about the first 6 weeks. After that, you won't notice it any more.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

> I have to move, so I wanted to clean things up properly for the next owner.

Did the next owner fall in love with your existing paint color choices? Patch it, paint it, and get out if it doesn't lower the selling price.

Just make sure to actually do a good patch job. A bad patch job is wayyy more noticeable than any paint color discrepancy.

---

> Kind of a dumb question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere, so I figured I'd ask here just to sanity check.

I won't judge =)

> Say I have a drywall repair

The texture of the drywall repair alone is going to provide an obvious enough difference unless you're a professional patcher and feather the paint fairly wide.

> that I need to paint over, and the previous owner of the house didn't leave a can of paint in this room's particular color, so I go try to get a gallon of matched paint somewhere, and it ends up not being a perfect match.

It almost never is a perfect match. Age changes paint in a way not reproduceable by simply color matching.

> I've heard in this case you have to paint "corner to corner", which I assume just means painting the whole wall, and not necessarily the whole room.

Yes, paint the whole wall.

> If that's the case, does this usually work out okay? Or is it often noticeable enough to where you need to paint the entire room?

Yes, it should work just fine.